# What is a (sharp) lower bound for $(2q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 2q - 2)/(q^{k+1} + q - 1)$ in terms of $q$ (and independent of $k$)?

Tags: inequality, optimization

**Question**

> What is a (sharp) lower bound for $$\frac{2q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 2q - 2}{q^{k+1} + q - 1}$$ in terms of $q$ (and independent of $k$)?

*Edit (April 29 2017)* Here, $q$ and $k$ are both positive integers.

**My Attempt**

$$\frac{2q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 2q - 2}{q^{k+1} + q - 1} = 2\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{q + (q-1)/q^k}\bigg) > 2\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{q}\bigg) = \frac{2(q-1)}{q}$$

Essentially, my question is whether we can do better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a lower bound that is independent of $k$, then this is the best you can do.  Your formula is equal to $2\left( 1-\frac{1}{q+(q-1)/q^{k}} \right)$, as you mention, which is a decreasing function.  If you take $\lim_{k \to \infty}$, you get $2 \left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)$. So for any $\epsilon > 0$, as soon as $k$ is large enough, you will be within $\epsilon$ of this lower bound. So it is not "sharp" in the sense that it is achieved by a specific $k$, but it is asymptotically sharp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MorganRodgers!